# What may cause error ('sysctl -n hw.optional.arm64' returned unexpected output: '') on Mac when running"flutter build ios"?

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, build

I'd be happy to provide more context on demand, sorry for being so generic, i really don't know what has caused this. If this helps: I have previously deleted two Info.plist files due to them existing as multiples in diferrent directories and then restored one of them, I have also tried reinstalling pods, ran flutter pub get and upgrade.

flutter doctor -v produces the same error, so maybe it has something to do with my flutter installation?

Comment: Does this happen on new flutter project also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I just needed to source ~/.zsh_profile.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone has the same issue after updating Flutter, I've spent some time on it and here is my solution:

Typing `which sysctl` on your terminal may result in `sysctl command not found`.
If this is the case, that means 'Sysctl' isn't on your path anymore (for whatever reason).
You need to [update your path](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide02.html#l23) to contain Sysctl.

Depending on your Mac, sysctl could be located in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin`.
In your zsh (or bash) config file, update your path with:
`:/usr/sbin`

Then type: `source [path to your config file]` and try it out with: `which sysctl`
If everything goes well, the path to Sysctl should appear.

You can now run `flutter doctor`

Cheers

Comment: For whom adding path in bashrc or zshrc `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this error is being thrown : the system cannot find `sysctl`

How to make it find ?

1. Open Terminal
2. Run: `nano ~/.zshrc`
3. Add the following line : `export PATH=/usr/sbin/:${PATH}`
4. Exit and Save
5. Run: `source ~/.zshrc`

Now, the error is fixed. Try again the command you were trying to run.