# Flutter simply showing 'sysctl -n hw.optional.arm64' returned unexpected output: ''

Tags: flutter, dart, sysctl

Not sure which details are relevant so I'll include as many as possible.

Had to upgrade flutter today and instead of working when I typed in 'flutter upgrade' into android studios terminal/Iterm2/terminal zsh I was met with the following response.

'sysctl -n hw.optional.arm64' returned unexpected output: ''

When I search for this issue the only thing i can [find is this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708385/what-may-cause-error-sysctl-n-hw-optional-arm64-returned-unexpected-output) which states that sysctl can't be found. The path does appear to be in my .zshrc but still not working. I can't use which or where sysctl as it just says 'sysctl not found'

When I try to upgrade flutter through brew (brew install --cask flutter) it downloads fine but on installing it throws the following error:

> ==> Purging files for version 3.3.5 of Cask flutter
> Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/opt/homebrew/bin/dart'.

I can't continue working as I need the new flutter version and it seems the web doesn't have much to show for this particular error.

I can't flutter --version, flutter doctor or anything of the sort as I just get the same message.

I'm using:

- MacOS monterey 12.6 macbook air.
- Android studios
- Iterm2
- Ohmyzsh

When I open android studios it shows me the following:

1. "Flutter device daemon #1 exited (exit code 1), stderr: 'sysctl -n hw.optional.arm64' returned unexpected output: '' in a pop up window.
2. Pubspec has been edited > get dependencies > Upgrade depenedencies: Both of which have the same error as in the title.
3. The current configured flutter SDK is not known to be fully supported. Please update your SDK and restart intelliJ which I think is what I've been trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer I hope will be helpful for others who have the same issue.

Other answers suggested a fix by just updating the path document (.zshrc) but this is what helped me as that did not and my paths were up to date.

Sadly, it's as simple as manually deleting all my flutter SDK files locally. Downloading them again (this time the latest one) and unzipping it into the same place. Didn't even have to update the path).

Worked a charm, issues appear to be all gone except that the dialogue in android studios is still saying that there are dependencies that need getting and upgrading (but doesn't go away even when I've run it).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the old flutter SDK, downloading the latest version, and setting it up again.
it works perfectly for me!